# "Organization" for homepage, but which types for the other pages?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I am new to Microdata and doing it for a website. It is a BPO company website and for its homepage, I have used `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"` and its child properties like `areaServed`, `makesOffer`, `location` (`PostalAddress`) etc.

Now I have to use Microdata for the other page of the same site, say InboundServices page, which in turn has 5 services like CustomerService etc.

So for these pages also, should I use same `Organization` itemscope or can I use `WebPage` itemscope or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) (or one of its subtypes, like [`AboutPage`](http://schema.org/AboutPage)) for every page on your site, including the homepage.

In addition, you can provide items (using suitable types) for every "entity" you have content about on the page.

For example, if every page contains your organization’s name and telephone number, you can (and should) have an [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) item on every page.

If such an item is the primary entity of the page (for example, the primary entity of the homepage is probably the `Organization`, the primary entity of a blog post page is [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting), etc.), you can use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity):

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://example.com/">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  </div>
</body>
```

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage" itemid="http://example.com/blog/hello-world">
  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  </article>
</body>
```